# Python Azure SQL - 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

I have to connect my script to a MSSQL hosted on Azure. I followed this tutorial from Microsoft : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/python/mac/step/2.html

I adapted it a bit for my need but the connection part is the same.
Then I'm have this error : `('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

I have installed the ODBC Driver with `brew` on MacOS and I can connect to my DB with the terminal with `sqlcmd` command.

EDIT : the `brew` option `--no-sandbox` for msodbcsql17 doesn't work for me. Issue seems to come because of this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you see when you run the following command: `odbcinst -q -d -n "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"`

Comment: @Ragnar did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes but I don't remember how sorry ! I had to install some dependencies.